# Laravel 5 - How to passing request data from route to controller

Tags: laravel-5, view, controller, routes, request

I am new in laravel,
How to passed request data into controller ? Just like happen on view ?

```
Route::get('/kelihatan', function (Request $request) {
    return view( 'pages' , [ 'page' => 'index' , '_request' => $request->all() ] );
});
```

How to passing request data to controller before passed into view or model ? Just like this ??

```
Route::get( '/{page}', 'UserController@show' );
```

Comment: now in your usercontroller do public function show(Request $request) { $page = $request->page;}

Comment: @KhanShahrukh what i mean was how to passed data in controller ? replacing "return view ..." with something that called controller and passed request data to that controller

Comment: @KhanShahrukh It's work but how about $_request ? Where is initialize ?

Answer (score 2):

Mention the path in route first depending upon the type of request i.e. Get or Post

```
 Route::get('/invite/{code}', 'MyController@get_my_action');
 Route::post('/invite/{code}', 'MyController@post_my_action');
```

Then in controller named as MyController create a function like

```
public function get_my_action($code){
 //your code goes here
}
or
public function post_my_action(Request $request, $code)
{
  //your code goes here
}
```

Comment: No, the Request is always present and is injected also with `get` or any other method. Just declare `get_my_action(Request $request, $code)` and try.

Answer (score 1):

With that route:

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'UserController@show');
```

In the controller you can do that:

```
 public function show()
 {
     $page = request()->route('page');
```

or that:

```
public function show($page)
```

or that:

```
public function show(Request $request, $page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Routes.php

```
Route::get( '/{page}', 'UserController@show' );
```

UserController.php

```
public function show($page) {
   dd($page);
}
```

Comment: what kind of "dd" ?

Comment: DD() is a Laravel function used to dump a variable and then exit the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller define your show function as below:

```
function show(Request $request)
{
   echo $request['page'];//or whatever data you want to pass

}    
///add follwoing line before you define controller

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```